# Trouble setting up 'Bachbot': Python gives no such command-error while installed correctly?

Tags: python, github, installation

I am trying to set up Bachbot (https://github.com/feynmanliang/bachbot) on my Windows 10 system in Python 3.5.1, Anaconda 4.0.0. Though doing several attempts, I keep failing at getting this to work. I downloaded the source code from github (didn't use Docker) and got to work.
First thing that's good to know is that I changed all print statements and added parantheses. Furthermore I changed every import of cPickle to

```
import _pickle as cPickle
```

since I'm using a newer version of Python. By doing this, I cleared all compile errors, but now I'm stuck at the first few steps of getting the program to work. When calling

```
bachbot chorales prepare_poly
```

I get an error

```
Usage: bachbot-script.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]
Error: no such command "chorales"
```

I figured the chorales script is part of the music21-module, which I installed on my computer using pip.
As far as I know I followed the installation steps more or less correctly (see github Getting Started and Workflow):

1. run activate script
2. run `pip install --editable .`

2.5 (installed the missing module music21)

3. run bachbot chorales prepare_poly

I suspect it has something to do with the entry point but I can't put a finger on what's wrong. I tried several re-installs but that does not seem to do the trick.

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, I was rushing to get the thesis in on time so the documentation is not the best!

The commands for building the polyphonic dataset and training the model are:

```
bachbot datasets prepare
bachbot datasets concatenate_corpus scratch/BWV-*.utf
bachbot make_h5
bachbot train
```

To use the model trained for `$ITER` iterations to generate samples with a sampling temperature of `$TMP`:

```
bachbot sample ~/bachbot/scratch/checkpoints/*/checkpoint_<ITER>.t7 -t <TEMP>
bachbot decode sampled_stream ~/bachbot/scratch/sampled_$TMP.utf
```

The first and last section of a [recent presentation I made](https://feynmanliang.github.io/bachbot-future-decoded) summarizes this workflow.

By the way, I would recommend using the Docker image described in the presentation I linked. While the CLI is in Python, the actual LSTM has additional dependencies (e.g. Lua, Torch, CUDA if you plan on using a GPU).

Comment: I ran into the same issue, but your commands partly solved this. Building and training the model seems to be working fine. Generating the sample creates the t7 file you referred to in your commands, but decoding it produces no output. Could this mean the model has to be trained more?

Comment: The `t7` file is a checkpoint of the model after `<ITER>` iterations of training; calling `bachbot sample` should produce a file `~/bachbot/scratch/sampled_$TMP.utf` which contains a score encoded in UTF symbols.

It may be possible that the sample you got doesn't contain an `END` symbol, which would result in `decode` returning nothing. I would try taking another sample or training for longer.